# How to send form data values received by parent page to the mvc controller

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc, iframe

I have three jsp pages and a spring controller.`LoginForm.jsp`,`userAccount.jsp` and `AccountSummary.jsp`.LoginForm will send data to userAccount which has an iframe.userAccount has links in it.Onclicking on one of the link AccountSummary page is displayed in the iframe of userAccount.

Now i need to pass the form data that is sent to the parent to the controller again if Accountsummary link is clicked.Then AccountSummary page is displayed in the iframe.Here the controller will validate the values and send appropriate data to account summary which will then be displayed
I tried adding the below code:

userAccount.jsp

```
<a href="./AccountSummary" target="frame1" id="AccSum" onclick="myfunc()">Account Summary</a>
        <form action="/MyBankProject/AccountSummary" method="post" target="frame1" id="myForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" value="${userName}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="password" value="${password}"/>
        </form>


<script>
function myfunc() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }

</script>
```

In the above code i am trying to take the form values sent to the parent, userName and password .And making them hidden and submitting so that controller will receive those values.But in vain the values are not passed to the controller.i couldn't figure out where i made a mistake.

I am new to javascript .I feel i explained the problem i am facing.kindly help me and let me know if i missed in conveying the problem.

Is there anything i missed.